# how to hide the iphone top bar?

Tags: iphone, ios, hide

I am new to ios development .......

When My App is run There is one BAR Appear on top of the screen .....Which Contains

network , digital clock and battery symbol

how i can hied this bar ?
  thanks in advance.........

```
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];


arryName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Savasana",@"Makarasana",@"Padahastasana",@"Natarajasana",@"Ustrasana",@"Hanumanasana",@"Garbhasana",@"Bhujapidasana",@"Astavakrasana(Eight-Angle Pose)",@"Mayurasana",@"Paschimottanasana",@"Janu Sirsasana",@"Urdhva Mukha Svanasana",@"Urdhva Dhanurasana",@"Bhujangasana",@"Bakasana",@"Surya Namaskar",@"Akarna Dhanur asana",@"Anjaneya asana",@"Ardha Chandra asana",@"Ardha Matsyendra asana",@"Baddha Kona Asana",@"Bala Asana",@"Chakra Asana",@"Dhanur asana",@"Ekapada asana",@"Garuda asana",@"Gomukha asana",@"Hala sana",@"Hasta Pada angusta",@"Matsya asana",@"Naga asana",@"Nataraja asana",@"Padma asana",@"Parivritta parshvakona",@"Pavana mukta asana",@"Sarvanga asana",@"Shalabha asana",@"Shava asana",@"Siddha asana",@"Simha asana",@"Sirsha asana",@"Tada asana",@"Trikona asana",@"Ugra asana",@"Ushtra asana",@"Vajra asana",@"Vira asana",@"Vriksha asana",@"Vrischika asana",@"Anjali Mudra",@"Ardha Matsyendrasana",nil];

arryImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"savasana_248.jpg",@"crocodile.jpg",@"Padahastasana.jpg",@"Natarajasana_248.jpg",@"Ustrasana_248.jpg",@"Hanumanasana_248.jpg",@"garbhasana.gif",@"bhujapidasana_1.jpg",@"Astavakrasana_248.jpg",@"Mayurasana.jpg",@"Paschimottanasa_248.jpg",@"JanuSirsasana.jpg",@"UrdhvaMukhaSvanasana.jpg",@"UrdhvaDhanurasana.jpg",@"Bhujangasana.jpg",@"Bakasana.jpg",@"1_Surya-namaskar.png",@"2-akarna_dhanurasana.png",@"3-Anjanya.png",@"4-ardha-chand.png",@"5-Adhamatsya.png",@"6-Baddha-kona.png",@"7-child-pose-balasana.png",@"8-Chakrasana-wheel-pose.png",@"9-Dhanura_asana-Bow_Pose.png",@"10-ekapada-asana-the-one-legged-pose.png",@"11-garudasana.png",@"12-gomukhasana.png",@"13-Halasan.png",@"14-Hasta.Padangusthasana.png",@"15-Matsyasana.png",@"16-naga-vj-g.png",@"17-natarajasana.png",@"18--padma.png",@"19--Parivrtta_Parsvakonasana-Revolved_Side_Angle_Pose.png",@"20-PAWANMUKTASANA.png",@"21-SHOULDER STAND.png",@"22--Salabhasana.png",@"23-Savasana.png",@"24-SIDDHASANA.png",@"25-Simha-asan-the lion.png",@"26-Sirsasana.png",@"27-Tada_Asana.png",@"28-Trikona_Asana.png",@"29-Ugra-asna-the Noblepose.png",@"30--ustrasana.png",@"31--Vijrasana.png",@"32-Vira-asna-the hero pose.png",@"33--Vriksha_Asana-Tree_Pose.png",@"34-VariskhikaiPad.png",@"AnjaliMudra.jpg",@"ArdhaMatsyendrasana.jpg",nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Project Info.plist file set Status bar is initially hidden YES, This will hide status bar for complete project.

[image]

And if you want to hide status bar in particular view the

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:<#(UIStatusBarAnimation)#>];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Comment: This function is deprecated in anything past iOS 4 (as far as I'm aware)

Comment: Nope: `- (void)setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden animated:(BOOL)animated` is deprecated because there are now multiple animations. sanjit's answer is a different method.

Comment: @nathanwhite for your kind information here I'm using setter and I don't think it is deprecated as Jesper mentioned. Thanks Jesper.

Comment: @Jesper Yes, you're right! Just checked it. Would help if I checked it on the mac I have next to me instead of trying to recall facts!

Answer (score 0):

It's called "Status Bar".

You can hide it by adding below line in "AppDidFinishLauching" method in "AppDelegate":

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

You can also hide it from .plist file.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In your `ProjectName-Info.plist` file set `Status bar is initially hidden`  `YES`

otherwise use `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

**Its Called Status bar:**

if you want to hide status bar then write following code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method `AppDelegate`

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
```

This code hide status bas with animation , if you want to remove animation then set `withAnimation:NO`

**Another Way that automatically set size of your viewController when status bar hide :**

```
 CGRect appFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
            self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds;
            self.view.window.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, appFrame.size.width, appFrame.size.height);
        }];
```